# p-value from scipy.stats.ttest_1samp

Tags: python, t-test, scipy.stats

I am running the one sample t-test using the following python code:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
mu, sigma = 0.67, 0.11
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 10000)
scipy.stats.ttest_1samp(s, popmean=0.60, alternative='greater')
```

which outputs
`Ttest_1sampResult(statistic=62.90183370907253, pvalue=0.0)`

Is that correct? I didn't expect the p-value to be 0 given that popmean is fairly close to the sample mean. I'm using scipy version 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too surprising that the p-value is very small. The difference between the true mean and the hypothesized mean (0.7) is actually quite large compared to the standard deviation (0.11), and the sample size is also quite large.

*Roughly* speaking, you're asking the test to compute the probability that data as extreme as yours was drawn from the "Null Hypothesized Distribution" in the plot below:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 0.67, 0.11
sample = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 10000)
dist = stats.norm(loc=0.6, scale=np.std(sample))

x = np.linspace(0, 1.2, 300)
plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x))
plt.hist(sample, density=True, bins=50)
plt.legend(("Null Hypothesized Distribution", "Data"), loc='lower left')
```

[image: Null Hypothesized Distribution vs Data]

It would be very surprising to draw the sample from the hypothesized distribution by chance, so the calculated probability is very low. If the standard deviation were larger or the sample size were much smaller, the story might be different.

In any case, you can verify the numerical result with other software. Matlab's `ttest` reports that the p-value for this data is indistinguishable from 0 (with the available precision), too.